# Is this possible to place a facebook call from an android app?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am new in android development. When a user press call button from my application , application should place a facebook voice call from my facebook account to another user but using my application and this must not redirect to facebook application.

Comment: please edit you question to comply with [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. This is a Messenger function. You can look at the Messenger API, which allows you to use Messenger functions, but there doesn't appear to be anything about voice calls.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation